# How to create new column in pandas based on a function relating to all previous values of another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiplication

For example, I have a data frame as follows with a column A:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 2, 5, 7, 1]})
```

I want to create another column 'B' based on multiplying all of the previous values of A asides from the first row, so it should read like this following the row number:

```
4, 8, 40, 280, 280
```

Is this achievable as a function inside pandas or is there another method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the cumulative product. There is a method of dataframes in pandas to apply the cumulative product (the name is `cumprod()`) :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 2, 5, 7, 1]})
df.cumprod()
```